# Unity 2D Quiz multiple errors throughout

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[The errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGW1k.png)Trying to create a simple 2D quiz with added effects, but keep encountering errors when developing it. i have included my code and the errors that I receive each time I run it. [Code within editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVWDB.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Question[] questions;
    private static List<Question> unansweredQuestions;
    private Question currentQuestion;

    void start ()
    {

        if (unansweredQuestions == null || unansweredQuestions.count = 0)
        {

            unansweredQuestions = questions.ToList<Question>();
        }
    }



}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the code class `Question`?

Comment: Will be nice to have the error message passed instead of a screan shoot. "_CS1061: 'List<Question>' does not contain a definition for 'count'_"... I guess you wanted Linq [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-5.0), and that a typo.

Comment: `unansweredQuestions.count = 0` is assignment, not a condition. Did you mean `unansweredQuestions.Count == 0` instead?

Comment: Perhaps it's time to use a real Editor. VS Community is free and do support simple verification like that.

Comment: Also, you might want to rename `start` to `Start`, if you want it to be called by Unity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. Your code seems to be full of typos ... For the error about the package make sure you have updated the package to the latest version, that it supports the Unity version you are using and maybe delete the `Library` folder and let Unity recreate

Answer (score 0):

The Message "'List' does not contain a definition for 'count' [...]" states, that unansweredQuestion does not have an implementation for "count". C# is case sensitive and the class List implements Count with a capital C. So try to replace .count with .Count and check if the code works afterwards.

Comment: This addresses only a [typo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo) and is only one of multiple issues in the code and OP's project in general